# Are any Zotac Zboxs suitable as HTPC / media centres?

Tags: mythbuntu, xbmc, mythtv

Are any Zotac Zboxes suitable as HTPC / media centres?

I'm after a fanless HTPC client in the living room to work with my MythTV server in my home office. I like the small compact form factor of the Zbox but what little I could find by Googling didn't clearly recommend any particular models for Ubuntu / MythTV / XBMC.

Can anyone recommend any models that work with little hassle?

Or, if there aren't any, are there other more Linux-friendly small format fanless PCs I should be looking at instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've been running a Zotac Zbox HD-NS21 for a couple of years as a dedicated mythbuntu frontend. Early on I noticed the HD ran pretty hot and it eventually failed. I jettisoned it and now run from a live usb stick. No issues. I'm currently running 12.04.3 64 bit with nividia 303.88, VDPAU normal. It's solid.